# (Python) Матрица, замена чисел

Tags: python, матрицы

Снизу прикрепила код для заполнения матрицы, если не удобен можете изменить.

Яркости пикселей рисунка закодированы числами от 0 до 255 в виде матрицы. Преобразовать рисунок в черно-белый по следующему алгоритму:
вычислить среднюю яркость пикселей по всему рисунку
все пиксели, яркость которых меньше средней, сделать черными (записать код 0), а остальные – белыми (код 255)

Пример:

Матрица А:

```
12 14 67 45
32 87 45 63 
69 45 14 11
40 12 35 15
```

Средняя яркость 37.88

Результат:

```
  0   0 255 255
  0 255 255 255
255 255   0   0
255   0   0   0
```

```
import random
A = []
imax = 0
jmax = 0
imin = 0 
jmin = 0
x = int(input("размер = "))
for i in range(x):
    A.append([])
    for c in range(x):
        A[i].append(random.randint(10,99))
min = A[0][0]
max = A[0][0]
print('Матрица А:')
for i in range(x):
    print()
    for c in range(x):
        print(" ",A[i][c],end = ' ')
for i in range(x):
    print()
    for c in range(x):
        if(A[i][c] > max):
            max = A[i][c]
            imax = i+1
            jmax = c+1
        if(A[i][c] < min):
            min = A[i][c]
            imin = i+1
            jmin = c+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 5
>>> matrix = np.random.randint(0,255,(x,x))
>>> matrix
array([[247,  21, 232, 117, 139],
       [  5, 182, 102,  24,  63],
       [234,  10,  86,  74, 210],
       [102, 164, 152, 174,  77],
       [141, 176, 120, 177, 139]])
>>> (matrix > matrix.mean()).astype(int) * 255
array([[255,   0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255,   0],
       [255, 255,   0, 255, 255]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать короче, используя generator и list comprehension:

```
from pprint import pprint

mtrx =  [
            [12, 14, 67, 45],
            [32, 87, 45, 63],
            [69, 45, 14, 11],
            [40, 12, 35, 15]
        ]

avg = sum(col for row in mtrx for col in row) / (len(mtrx) * len(mtrx[0]))
new_mtrx = [[255 if col > avg else 0 for col in row] for row in mtrx]

pprint(new_mtrx, width=30)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0, 255, 255],
 [0, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 0, 0],
 [255, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: только у вас не короче, а наоборот. кроме того, numpy эффективнее, чем генерация списков.

Comment: @strawdog Имел в виду: короче, чем в вопросе.